# Getting data from website via requests.get and receiving 401 response

Tags: python

I’m trying to get JSON with products details from the website https://www.highspiritsuae.com/shop?Collection=WINE by sending `request.get`.

I’m very new in interaction with web, however by using of developer tools in Chrome was able to find element that gives this JSON and look at headers, Chrome sends to get it.

I have created few rows of code, however, receive 401 as a result. As per google it means authorization issue, but when I open website through browser it does not require any login/password.

```
url ='https://www.highspiritsuae.com/_api/wix-ecommerce-storefront-web/api?o=getFilteredProducts&s=WixStoresWebClient&q=query'
#url = 'https://www.highspiritsuae.com/_serverless/analytics-reporter/facebook/event'

t = requests.get(
    
    url,

     params = {
     "isPremium": "true",
     "metaSiteId": "fc3611a3-f8bf-4a5d-8979-51b24f693fc1",
     "origin": "Stores",
     "userId": "92f732fb-9623-461f-8e2b-40e2d1e9a49a",
     "visitorId": "f2b49b1d-3248-4551-af5f-94ae17ece5c0",
     "_internalEventId": "85640bb5-83d4-425f-98d3-807c255741cc",
     "eventName": "AddProductImpression"
       },
    
    headers= {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
    )

print(t)
```

Will really appreciate if someone can have a look and advise what I’m missing.

Comment: 401 status code means that your request needs an authorization

Comment: This is understandable, my question is since browser doesn’t require authorisation, how to emulate this request ?

Comment: it's very natual to fail. and that's a important reason why frameworks such as `selenium` exists. please have a try.

Comment: @Sergey if you try opening the same url that's in the code in a browser, you will get error 401.

Comment: @bereal excatly

Comment: @LeiYang the `Selenium` solves another issue. It can execute javascript and load the page as expected. This is an authorization issue. Read about `401` status code here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Comment: web apps often need complex cookies/js for authorization, that's too complicated for the OP(or anyone who use plain http requests), that's why i said selenium could solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to emulate this request?

What am I suggesting is to open *network* of browser dev tools and see if there is no `authorization` header in browser request then it probably uses cookies.
The easy way to emulate the request is to make right-click on the request and copy it as cURL then using [cURLConverter](https://curlconverter.com/) you can convert your request to Python's `requests` and compare it with your code.

[image]